# New-DynamicDistributionGroup : Cannot bind parameter 'RecipientFilter' to the target

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I try to run the following command:

```
New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name "All Company Office"
-OrganizationalUnit 'domain/A1/Distribution Groups'
-RecipientFilter {((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox')
-and (Office -eq 'Fornebu')
–and (Company -eq 'Broadnet'))}
-RecipientContainer 'domain/A1/Users'
```

But I get the following error:

```
New-DynamicDistributionGroup : Cannot bind parameter 'RecipientFilter' to the target.
Exception setting "RecipientFilter": """ is not a valid operator. For a list of
supported operators see the command help.
"((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (Office -eq 'Fornebu') –and (Company -eq 
'Broadnet'))" at position 64."

At line:1 char:140
+ New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name "_TESTDG Alle Broadnet Fornebu" 
-OrganizationalUnit 'corp.local/A1/Distribution Groups' -RecipientFilter <<<<  
{((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (Office -eq 'Fornebu')
–and (Company -eq 'Broadnet'))} -RecipientContainer 'corp.local/A1/Users'
+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-DynamicDistributionGroup],
ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :
ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewDynamicDistributionGroup
```

I've tried "the google" to no avail.
Please help:)
(using powershell 2.0 by the way)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvradmin/thread/97a984e9-c97a-4a9c-aa2c-358761310e82) alludes to the filter having a problem with your parentheses. Try this instead:

```
-RecipientFilter {((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (Office -eq 'Fornebu' -and Company -eq 'Broadnet'))}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I managed to solve it though.. It turns out that my - signs had somehow changed when copy and pasting from online examples. I replaced them and it works..

Comment: Interesting. I've had a dos prompt bite me like that, but not powershell; maybe I just don't recall copying and pasting into one, though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had copied sample code through a browser.. I replaced all the pasted dash-signs (-) with my own and it worked... Weird!